# Create List<String> with xml format and how to verify it

Tags: java, xml, collections, dictionary, stack

i have this questions

1.- the firts one is how can i create a `list<String> list` with XML format NOT USING a .xml

for example, i want to put this on the list:

```
<list_conferences>
<conference>
<code> 0001371 </code>
<name> "examples" </name>
</conference>
</list_conferences>
```

2.- how can i verify if that list is *well-formed* using stacks

greetings

Comment: Is this an assignment involving simple XML validation? What have you tried? If you have specific problems, we can help, but as it stands, this should be closed as "not a real question"

Comment: What does List<String> list contain from your xml? You question is unclear.

Comment: A List<String> is an object, not a file, I don't see how it could have an xml format.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at JAXB for example.
JAXB helps you the convert an XML string to java bean, and vice versa